# Blazor 6.0 Webassembly 'downloadFileFromStream' was undefined)

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I have the following code in wwwroot/index.html.

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
<script>
    window.downloadFileFromStream = async (fileName, contentStreamReference) => {
        const arrayBuffer = await contentStreamReference.arrayBuffer();
        const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer]);
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const anchorElement = document.createElement('a');
        anchorElement.href = url;
        anchorElement.download = fileName ?? '';
        anchorElement.click();
        anchorElement.remove();
        URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    }
    </script>
```

In the .razor page I have

```
await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("downloadFileFromStream", fileName, streamRef);
```

This was all added per the Microsoft doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-downloads?view=aspnetcore-7.0, but I have the error:

Error: Could not find 'downloadFileFromStream' ('downloadFileFromStream' was undefined).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what works for me:

1. Added to **index.html**:

   `<script src="SaveFile.js"></script>`
2. Created file **SaveFile.js** (in wwwroot) with content:

```js
    async function downloadFileFromStream(fileName, contentStreamReference)
    {
     const arrayBuffer = await contentStreamReference.arrayBuffer();
     const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer]);
     const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
     var link = document.createElement('a');
     link.download = fileName;
     link.href = url
     document.body.appendChild(link);
     link.click();
     URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
     document.body.removeChild(link);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is WASM, but I created the js file as suggested and added to wwwroot/index.html <script src="SaveFile.js"></script> and still have the same error

Comment: @Christian Oops sorry I corrected that. I tried this in WASM and it worked for me. Can you make sure SaveFile.js is present in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Add `app.js` file to `wwwroot` folder.

**app.js**

```js
function saveAsFile(bytesBase64, contentType, fileName) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.download = fileName;
    link.href = `data:${contentType};base64,${bytesBase64}`;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

Add `<script src="app.js"></script>` in the `index.html` after `<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>`.

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    ...
    ...
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <div class="position-absolute bottom-50 start-50 translate-middle">
            <div class="text-center text-dark">
                <img src="images/logo/512x512.png" width="64" alt="Learning Center" />
                <div class="mt-2">Loading...</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```cs
private async Task DownloadInvoiceAsync(EventArgs e)
{
    int invoiceNumber = 123123123;
    var invoicePdf = await _invoiceService.DownloadInvoiceAsync(invoiceNumber);
    await _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("saveAsFile", invoicePdf.Content, invoicePdf.ContentType, invoicePdf.FileName);
}
```

API should return data in the below format:

```cs
return new InvoicePdf(Convert.ToBase64String(content), "application/octet-stream", $"invoice-{invoice.InvoiceNumber}.pdf");
```

**NOTE:** In the above example `Content` is Base64String.

**InvoicePdf.cs**

```cs
public record InvoicePdf(string Content, string ContentType, string FileName);
```